# Using Swift enum to reduce number of parameters in a function

Tags: swift, function, api-design, single-responsibility-principle

I'm facing the typical problem of too much parameters in a function.

```
protocol OfflineController {
    func cache(request: OfflineRequestConvertible, forId id: String?, data: Data, keepAliveUntil keepAlive: Date?, completion: @escaping OfflineControllerCompletionHandler)
    func get(request: OfflineRequestConvertible, forId id: String?, ifBefore before: Date?, completion: @escaping OfflineControllerCompletionHandler)
    func delete(request: OfflineRequestConvertible, forId id: String?, completion: @escaping OfflineControllerCompletionHandler)
}
```

As you can see it is a regular caching system with functions to `cache`, `get` the cached data and `delete` cached data.

Known solutions to this problem are:

1. *Take a look at SRP violations*. I don't think it's the case here, at least I don't see any.
2. *Try to encapsulate related data in new types and pass an instance*. This is clear in the classic example `foo(x: Double, y: Double)` being converted to `foo(point: Point)` but in this case I cannot identify nothing that can be encapsulated (maybe `request` and `id`), and it'll be an explosion of types as each method have a different signature. Also, it translates the complexity to the consumer of the API, having to instantiate a concrete object per method.
3. *Create a common parameter type and use a builder to populate it depending on the method invoked*. IMHO it obscures the API, how I know I have to send `keepAliveUntil` when executing `cache` and not `get` or `delete`?

I was delaying the solution to this problem until I recalled Swift's `enum`. Now I'm thinking on something like this:

```
enum OfflineControllerAction {
    case cache(request: OfflineRequestConvertible, data: Data, id: String?, keepAliveUntil: Date?)
    case get(request: OfflineRequestConvertible, id: String?, ifBefore: Date?)
    case delete(request: OfflineRequestConvertible, id: String?)
}

protocol OfflineController {
    func execute(_ action: OfflineControllerAction, completion: @escaping OfflineControllerCompletionHandler)
}
```

Maybe it's more elegant but I think this is very similar to point 2, and I'm keeping the original methods to being dispatched in the enum switch.

The question is, what do you think about this solution? Is it another approach I don't know? Maybe there are no solution and this is simply a problem of design (SRP)?

Comment: If you provide default values (e.g. `= nil` for optionals) than 5 parameters does not have to be too many. However, wrapping the parameters into an object, e.g. called `Request`, which can also have a `method` (instead of `get`, `delete`, `cache`...) is a classic solution.

Comment: It is a protocol so I cannot use default parameters (there are solutions to mimic them but they aren't elegant).

Comment: True. You would have to add that in an extension using default implementation.

Comment: This is an untested idea, so may not work. How about you define some constants for parameter names, and simply take a Dictionary<String, Any> as the only parameter? Then resolve the parameters inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Step Builder Pattern may be a way to add parameters incrementally and depending on your needs. Also it lets you define parameters that are mandatory in some cases but not in others (as you mention in point 3).

Simplifying you have to define a protocol for each parameter setter the builder is going to have. Next is to define a protocol chain, so each protocol defines the builder setter method and it returns the next protocol in the sequence. Finally the builder has to implement all the protocols.

Using this pattern you define a particular sequence of invocations to builder methods, letting you create alternate paths in the invocations sequence.

Comment: Thank you @Mario_io, this is what I was looking for :) As this is something new for me I wrote an article about it: https://medium.com/@mario.negro.martin/using-step-builder-pattern-in-swift-f8bd6ecd3677#.gxb94xz43